# AJAX post to Google Spreadsheet from Node.js/ Express fails

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express, heroku

I've researched a few questions similar to this but none have helped solve my problem...

**Posting to a Google Spreadsheet app from a simple Node.js/ Express script on Heroku (not accessed through the browser) doesn't show up any errors but still fails. Can anyone understand why?**

I've created a very small app with Node.js and Express. It basically listens for messages from a Slack channel, evaluates and strips parts of the message it needs and then posts them to a Google Spreadsheet to be stored.

I'm using the node modules `express` for receiving data posted from Slack and  `ajax-request` to handle the AJAX post to Google Spreadsheets. It looks a little something like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var ajaxRequest = require('ajax-request');

var app = express();

// Other app.stuff

app.post('/test', function (req, res, next) {

  var userName = req.body.user_name;
  var message = req.body.text || '';

  // DOES SOME OTHER STUFF...

  postToSpreadsheet(userName, message);

});

function postToSpreadsheet(user, id) {

  ajaxRequest({ // Post request

    url: 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/abcdefg123456/exec', // Google Spreadsheet app url
    method: 'POST',
    data: {Id : id, User : user}

  }, function(err, res, body) { // Request callback

    console.log("ERROR: " + err + " / BODY: " + body);

  });

}
```

I receive **no errors** from the request callback, however the `body` of the post contains the HTML from Google's file not found page, which makes me think it's posting to an incorrect url.

**I know it's not:**

- A Google script problem. The Google script works fine and the published app is public and accessible to anyone. When I just enter the url with encoded parameters into my browser e.g. `https://script.google.com/macros/s/abcdefg123456/exec?Id=id&User=johnsmith` it works and stores the parameters in my Google Spreadsheet.
- An data to url params serialisation problem - I've tried just posting to the url above with pre-defined parameters and no `data` option.
- A dependency problem - I've tried to get it working with a few different AJAX node modules.